# Center a carousel horizontally and vertically on page

Tags: html, css

Anyone know why carousel is not centering horizontally? I'm using `slick.js` for carousel.

Have set `display: table; margin: 0 auto;` to center horizontally but its not working.

`jsfiddle` .. http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/4qpejg98/1/

[image]

`html` ..

```
<div class="centerHorizontally parent">
    <div class="halfWidth child">
        <div class="slider multiple-items">
            <div>
                <div class="centerHorizontally">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="centerHorizontally">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="centerHorizontally">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="centerHorizontally">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="centerHorizontally">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="centerHorizontally">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="centerHorizontally">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`css`:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
}
.parent > .child {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.slider {
    width: 50%;
    height: 10%;
}
.slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before {
    color:#808080;
}
.centerHorizontally {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.halfWidth {
    width: 50%;
}
```

`javascript`:

```
$('.multiple-items').slick({
    infinite: false,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 5,
    dots: true
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `margin: 0 auto` to `.slider` div.

```
.slider {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4qpejg98/2/